# ODI-2012 Error occurred while updating schedules :ODI-10147: Repository type mismatches

Tags: linux, oracle, hadoop, kerberos, oracle-data-integrator

I got this message  when i try to update schedulers on ODI studio. I can't figure who to solve this problem.

The ODI standalone alone agent is correctly set-up in the topology of ODI studio.

this is a part of the agent's log situated in /home/odi/agents/log/myAgent.log

[...]

```
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

[...]

```
Caused by: oracle.odi.core.config.NotWorkRepositorySchemaException: ODI-10147: Repository type mismatches.
```

A can give more informations on demand.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For reasons unknown to me my previous post was against the rules. I'll try again.

The error indicates a difference in repository *version* rather than *type*, and that can be quite specific. There is a difference between 12.2.1.3 and 12.2.1.4 repositories, for example.